# Are my exercises and their reps and sets good for fat loss?

Tags: workout-routines, upper-body-workout, core, lower-body-strength

I've organized my workout into 6 days: 2 sessions of upper-body workouts, lower-body workouts, and core workouts. The 7th day is a rest day. I am working out at home so these are my options. Please tell me if these exercises are good and if their sets and reps amount is healthy. Thank you:

https://alphaprogression.com/en/73lIl2 (Day 1 Upper Body Session)
https://alphaprogression.com/5dTMZl (Day 2 Lower Body Session)
https://alphaprogression.com/9nWL2I (Day 3 Core Body Session)
https://alphaprogression.com/3Twuyg (Day 4 Upper Body Session)
https://alphaprogression.com/5vbB9R (Day 5 Lower Body Session)
https://alphaprogression.com/9NevZN (Day 6 Core Body Session)

Comment: If your primary goal is fat loss, the specifics of your workout routine aren't particularly important. All you need is a calorie deficit and, preferably, a macro split with high protein and low fat.

Comment: When it comes to fat loss, the most important aspect of your training is that you enjoy your workouts, thus helping you stay consistent.

Comment: @Ethan - If you could flesh that out a bit, it would make a good answer. Comments are subject to being deleted at any time.